# I want to reduce image size before saving in my web folder in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to reduce image size and save reduced image to my image folder. Following is what I have done to save image but problem is reduce image is not saved into my image folder.

HOW TO SAVE reduced IMAGE IN MY IMAGE FOLDER IN MVC4..?

Below is my code to save the image:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(TblProduct ObjProducts)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files[0]; 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(File.FileName);
        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename);             

        ///save file
        string oldImage = File.FileName;
        string NewFileName = ObjProducts.ManualP_Id + ".JPG";
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(NewFileName);
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ProductImg"), NewFileName);
        File.SaveAs(path);                
        ObjProducts.Image =NewFileName;
        ObjProducts.IsActive = true;
        ObjProducts.IsDelete = false;
        ObjProducts.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.TblProducts.Add(ObjProducts);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("DisplayProduct", "PanelProduct");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream, true, true);
 var bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth,newHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(img,
        new Rectangle(0,0,newWidth,newHeight),
        clipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
bitmap.Save(path,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function to scale and compress your image to  the desired resolution:

```
int Height = 600;
int Width = 800;    
private Image Scale(Image imgPhoto)
    {
        float sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        float sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        float destHeight = 0;
        float destWidth = 0;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        // force resize, might distort image
        if (Width != 0 && Height != 0)
        {
            destWidth = Width;
            destHeight = Height;
        }
        // change size proportially depending on width or height
        else if (Height != 0)
        {
            destWidth = (float)(Height * sourceWidth) / sourceHeight;
            destHeight = Height;
        }
        else
        {
            destWidth = Width;
            destHeight = (float)(sourceHeight * Width / sourceWidth);
        }

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap((int)destWidth, (int)destHeight,PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,new Rectangle(destX, destY, (int)destWidth, (int)destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, (int)sourceWidth, (int)sourceHeight),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```